# SharePoint Column does not exist when attribute overwrite=TRUE

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, error, site-column

I am trying to fix an error by changing site column  attribute to `overwrite=true`

And I get Column does not exist when activate the feature , when putting that attribute back to `false` there is no problem activating the feature. I know this will solve the original problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">  
<Field
   ID="{d5a16ccb-f7d5-4fbe-99c9-4924f71c302d}"
   Name="PagesTypeToShowGUID"
   FieldRef="{62006e5a-6ae9-4470-b130-b89231571503}"
   ShowField="ContentTypeGUID"
   List="Lists/PagesOnList"
   Overwrite="TRUE"
   WebId=""
   DisplayName="$Resources:SiteColumns,PagesToShowGUID;"
   Type="LookupMulti"
   Mult="TRUE"
   Required="TRUE"
   Group="$Resources:SiteColumns,SiteColumnsGroup;">
</Field>
</Elements>
```

Comment: It might help to mention the problem you actually need to solve; there may be another way to solve it.

Comment: the error is :
<nativehr>0x80070057</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>
I found out Overwrite property suppose to be TRUE

in the Dev environment its working but failed to apply changes to test Environment